# obtaining Kerberos ticker for hdfs user throws an error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I need to call a command using the hdfs user. My environment is kerberos-authenticated, so, to do that I called the following command to obtain a kerberos ticket for the hdfs user:

```
kinit -V -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab hdfs
```

That command threw the following error:

```
Using default cache: /run/user/krb5cc/krb5cc_MyUserID
Using principal: hdfs@MyRealm
Using keytab: /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab
kinit: Password has expired while getting initial credentials
```

When I try to use sudo in the command to be

```
sudo kinit -V -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab hdfs
```

I get the following error

```
Using default cache: /run/user/krb5cc/krb5cc_0
Using principal: hdfs@MyRealm
Using keytab: /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab
kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for hdfs@MyRealm while getting initial credentials
```

The reason I though I may need to use sudo is because the keytab file has permission "-r--r-----" and root is the owner.

Any idea how can I obtain a tgt for hdfs user so that I can use it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the principal of the keytab using below java command

```
klist -k /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab
```

It will display the principal of the keytab. Use that principal to authenticate with the keytab using kinit command.

Comment: I tried to check the pricipals using "klist -kte /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab" and it gave me a list of principal names. Isn't it the same? an example of an item in the retrieved list is "16 06/22/2016 21:45:39 hdfs-clusterName@myRealm (encryptionTechnique)"

Comment: Yes you can use "klist" also. Is it shows the principals as "hdfs"? if not, use the retrieved principal for getting ticket instead of "hdfs"

Comment: I was using a wrong principal name,  "klist -kte /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab" displayed the principal name that I was looking for which I was able to use after that. Thanks kumar!